# How is 'diagonal' implemented in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, github

I'm interested in the way numpy implements the `diagonal` of an array. I searched [the github repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) for `def diagonal(`, and found mentions in three files: `numpy/__init__.pyi, numpy/core/fromnumeric.py` and `numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyi`, but these don't implement the function. In particular, in the last file it says

```
if isinstance(a, np.matrix):
        return asarray(a).diagonal(offset=offset, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
    else:
        return asanyarray(a).diagonal(offset=offset, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
```

When I click on `.diagonal`, I only get the three files I listed above, again. Does this mean that `trace` is not implemented in Python but C? How can I find the code for this function?

Comment: Almost all underlying functionality in numpy is implemented in C (or Cython, or in some BLAS/LAPACK library, which could be implemented inC, Fortran, assembly ...)

Comment: The `diagonal` doc page has a `[source]` link, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1513-L1640

Comment: Sorry, the link was for the function version, which delegates to the method.  And `arr.diagonal??` in ipython shows it's a builtin, i.e compiled.  `np.diag` is python and viewable, though only the 'setting' version is there.  The extract diagonal from 2d uses `diagonal`.

Comment: Do you want me to delete my answer?  I'm guessing the down vote is yours!

Comment: Why do you want to know this?  I think I found the source code in `item_selection.c`, but you'd have a lot familiarity with `numpy` and `c` to make much sense of it.

Comment: @hpaulj I wasn't online since yesterday so the downvote couldn't be mine. 'PyArray_Diagonal' is helpful, how did you find it? And is there no way to make sure one actually found the correct implementation in the source code from knowing only the Python function name?

Comment: Having learned from the `[source]` link and ipython that it's compiled, I focused on `src` file.  In a `github` search those would be `.c` as opposed to `.py`.  Tracking down `c` code is tricky, since there's a fair amount of preprocessing.  So it's a mix of searching, guess work, and looking for related names.

Answer (score -1):

numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c

has a `PyArray_Diagonal` function.  I believe this is the core source code.

Most of the code calculates `shape` and `strides`, and then passes them to a `PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase` call.  I believe this is equivalent to the `as_strided` method I demonstrate below.

===

```
In [268]: arr=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

for the main diagonal:

```
In [269]: arr.diagonal()
Out[269]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

It is builtin - compiled, as we can see from the `ipython` query:

```
In [289]: arr.diagonal??
Docstring:
a.diagonal(offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=1)
...
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

But indexing a diagonal is not a hard task.  a simple indexing way to do the same:

```
In [274]: arr[np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]
Out[274]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

other indexing arrays can be used to get other diagionals.  With advanced indexing like this the result is a copy, not a view.

`np.diag` uses `flat` to set the diagonal values.  It can also be used extract the diagonal:

```
In [275]: arr.flat[::4]
Out[275]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

This too is a copy.

Advanced `as_strided` can also be used to make a `view`:

```
In [281]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(3,), strides=(32,))
In [282]: x
Out[282]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

showing that it's a view:

```
In [283]: x += 1        
In [284]: arr
Out[284]: 
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 5],
       [6, 7, 9]])
```

The basic ideas could be extended to handle higher dimensions, and offset diagonals.

The `flat` indexing is close enough in time, that I suspect `diagonal` uses something similar:

```
In [290]: timeit arr.diagonal()
200 ns ± 2.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [291]: timeit arr.flat[::4]
434 ns ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [292]: timeit arr[np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]
5.48 µs ± 188 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Looking at the `array_interface` for the array and its `diagonal`, suggests it is using a compiled version of my `as_strided` code [281]:

```
In [294]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[294]: 
{'data': (50545760, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 3),
 'version': 3}

In [295]: arr.diagonal().__array_interface__
Out[295]: 
{'data': (50545760, True),
 'strides': (32,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

### more strided test

As a further test of my strided idea, make a 3d array and use the axes parameters.

```
In [330]: arr = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
In [331]: arr
Out[331]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

`diagonal` with axes values:

```
In [332]: arr.diagonal(0,1,2)
Out[332]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [4, 7]])
In [333]: _.__array_interface__
Out[333]: 
{'data': (50211088, True),
 'strides': (32, 24),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

A strided view using the same shape and strides:

```
In [334]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(2,2), strides=(32,24))
Out[334]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [4, 7]])
```

I won't get into how it derived those strides from `arr.strides` (32,16,8), or how it handles offset.  Working with strides requires a mix of reasoning and trial-and-error.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to show in the second part of your answer. My question wasn't which alternative ways of computing the diagonal are there in numpy, but how numpy itself implements it. I took a look at the C code in 'PyArrow Diagonal', and I don't see the connection between that code and, for example, 'as_strided'.

Comment: For example, diagonal is trivial to implement with list comprehensions, or for a fixed number of dimensions. But I want to understand the (C) code for strided arrays with a variable number of dimensions.

Comment: I added a 3d example.  Deriving the required `strides` is essentially a book keeping detail.  The core of the action is that it returns a `view` with new shape and strides.

Comment: Do you have some reference on how to derive the strides?